# A better way of doing this evaluation in Python

Tags: python, list, evaluation

I have function that delivers a List with a single element of the form `ax+b` where a and b are (multi)digit characters and there is exactly one 'x'.

I then swap the x for a number and use eval on the result.

For example with the single element `[64/243*x - 283/243]` I apply

```
new_word=words.replace('x','7')
```

to get `[64/243*7 - 283/243]`

which I then evaluate

```
z=eval(new_word)
```

What I want to achieve is a loop where  I put various numbers in for 'x', with different List elements.

Before I do that, is there a better/slicker/faster way of evaluating something like  `[64/243*x - 283/243]` for different values of 'x' other than  using eval?

Or point me to the Old Question that you think is an answer to my question.

Comment: is there any reason to keep it as a list? seems much easier if it's just an expression. then you can evaluate it in a list comprehension for various values of `x`: `[64/243*x - 283/243 for x in (7,8)]`

Comment: No, how do I convert it to an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a class that can display and evaluate a linear expression:

```py
from fractions import Fraction
from random import randint

class Linear:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = Fraction(randint(0, 10), randint(1, 10))
        self.b = Fraction(randint(0, 10), randint(1, 10))
        self.func = lambda x: self.a*x + self.b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Linear(a={self.a}, b={self.b})'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.a}*x+{self.b}'

    def __call__(self,x):
        return self.func(x)

eq = Linear()
print(repr(eq))
for x in range(1,6):
    print(f'{eq} where x={x} => {eq(x)}')
```

Output:

```
Linear(a=3/5, b=4/5)
3/5*x+4/5 where x=1 => 7/5
3/5*x+4/5 where x=2 => 2
3/5*x+4/5 where x=3 => 13/5
3/5*x+4/5 where x=4 => 16/5
3/5*x+4/5 where x=5 => 19/5
```

Comment: I will give that a go.